# How to access nested type of: K extends keyof T, T[K], e.g. T[K]["someSubField"]

Tags: typescript, typing

I have the following function:

```
const fieldDefinitions = {
  a: { id: "14", "default": "none" },
  b: { id: "15", "default": 0 },
  c: { id: "16", "default": 0 },
};

const setFields = <T extends typeof fieldDefinitions, K extends keyof T>(fieldValues: { fieldName: K, value: T[K]["default"] }[]) => {
  //logic to set fields
}
```

I want to type it in a way that it will only accept field values that are of the same type as the default value.

E.g.:

```
setFields([
  { fieldName: "a", value: "somestring" },
  { fieldName: "c", value: 123 },
])
//should work because:
// - default of a is "none" which is a string
// - default of c is 0 which is a number


setFields([
  { fieldName: "a", value: 123 },
  { fieldName: "c", value: "somestring" },
])
//should NOT work because:
// - default of a is "none" which is a string, but a number is given
// - default of c is 0 which is a number, but a string is given
```

Here is where I get the error in the typedefinition:

```
value: T[K]["default"]
```

It says: Type '"default"' cannot be used to index type 'T[K]'

So my question is, what is the right way to access the type of the "default" property of T[K] here?

Here is the code in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwKYBsAmARJiwKg8CGAXhgG8AoGGAQwC5yYE0GAiARgBZWAaGNbDQCuKKGzDgkrGAF8eVGACMGZJixgcArL36CRYmAAZZ86sBVq27AGw6BcYaIbG5FGQG4KFAPQAqX1S%20MAAqABZI8MjoMABuNChCERChICJoShFIYHAgAE7ASOlQIBkwUOEwEDQAthFQAJ4ADhE0ROUR9o6wcQkRCGBlFfb9eARggd4UoJCwEEhQAGJRaESkADzBMEgAHlBZK2VNSCBwkaiY2CP4hHwA0lu7%200QA1kj1JyEAfAAUiOcAavFEhALH90AA5GpIBi3Pg9RIMYIAbVuAF0kaxOvpWKjZEjUQBKEifcgKbzeFAgADmCGAZRKc1gYJWbi8Pm8lRSaRgAHc8s8KIylucIN8kQpVMzIbU2DQdPDoRoICBatBcv0qdJXNRJctpYrWMB5UDFewAEwAZhMFEJXnJyVS0QksD5uQFQuWovFOrOEKhsuNvQY5qt2sYUv9GiNcJNbGVqqg6rAmuthKAA):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `T` extends `typeof fieldDefinitions` that means it could be any subtype that has any other properties that do not have an object type with `default`.

`T` is not really used, you only want `fieldDefinitions` not a subtype of it, so you could do the following:

```
type FieldDefinitions = typeof fieldDefinitions
/**
 * The field value should be enforced to be the same type as the default value in the definition
 */
const setFields = <K extends keyof FieldDefinitions>(fieldValues: { fieldName: K, value: FieldDefinitions[K]["default"] }[]) => {
  //logic to set fields
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwKYBsAmARJiwKg8CGAXhgG8AoGGAQwC5yYE0GAiARgBZWAaGNbDQCuKKGzDgkrGAF8eVGACMGZJixgcArL36CRYmAAZZ86sBVq27AGw6BcYaIbG5FGQG4KFKAE8ADkgwAGLI6Fg4eASQJDC+ASBw8KGY2Ai4+IQUAPQAVDlUOTAAKgAWgYioaDAAbjQoQoEQJSAiVYqBSGBwIABOwEhVUCBKgVBlMBA0ALaj-oE0RGOB9o6wtfWBabHj9mmR4AVZFKCQsBBIUCGVRKQAPADSMEgAHlCdaEQA1kg+CcHJ4T2GUgAD4ABQVdAANTqDQgFkhaAActMkAx7nx1g0GFcwql0lEIABte4AXSJrBW+lYpNkRNJAEoSCDyAoslkUCAAOYIYCxYbnWCIiBuLzZLITZqtGAAd16nwogtxHzBRIUqkRKJmbBoOixaI0EBAM2gPTSXOkrmoGuSWoNrGAethBvYACYAMwmCiMrzspotdAwCSwOU9BVK5IQVXqpKVO06p0bBhuz1Wxia1FsR2Y51sI0mqBmsAWr2MoA)

However this **will not** actually solve the problem you are trying to solve. It will not ensure that in an element of the array, the key and value are correlated (the `value` will be typed as a union of all present keys)

The real solution here is to use a mapped type as the parameter. This technique, sometimes called a reversed mapped type,  will ensure TS can follow the correlation inside each element of the array:

```
const fieldDefinitions = {
  a: { id: "14", "default": "none" },
  b: { id: "15", "default": 0 },
  c: { id: "16", "default": 0 },
};

type FieldValues<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: { fieldName: T[P], value: typeof fieldDefinitions[T[P] & FieldDefinitionKeys]['default'] }
}

type FieldDefinitionKeys = keyof typeof fieldDefinitions
const setFields = <T extends [FieldDefinitionKeys] | FieldDefinitionKeys[]>(fieldValues: FieldValues<T>) => {
}



// works
setFields([
  { fieldName: "a", value: "somestring" },
  { fieldName: "c", value: 123 },
])

//does not work
setFields([
  { fieldName: "a", value: 123 },
  { fieldName: "c", value: "somestring" },
])
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwKYBsAmARJiwKg8CGAXhgG8BYAKBhgEMAucmBNJgIgEYAWdgGhjs02OgFcUUdhzDgk7GAF8+1WgCMmZFm0GcArP0HC4YiVJgAGRcpoxgGrR04A2A0JHjJTS0uoKA3NTUUACeAA5IMABiyOgAanQookgQADwAKgB8JOQqtDAA2gAKLGAwANZIwSBwMGkAuvaIqGgAcnQAtkhMaUV1AgBuCUlMIeHV8DGY2Ai4+IT5PYV1MABkUZNYOHgEYADSlRB1+QDkRiZQx8sKvoFUoxHRzZsz2+D7wUSkFVU19+NN6Gesx2EGooEgsAgSCgj3Qnxg6RgSAAHlAkGA0ER8rCpls5nsDssAD7rJ7TYFvA75OoZAAUALQ8USySYOKZSVSmQAlCQspQqNcqLdqAB6EUwADuIAATmVQVQoTDJhBaflcpoGW1Ohw6AZBsyOBAQJ1oNKZgBzeQ+GwayZarqCYB6oYOzgAJgAzFZqHUubcxWgQMkYDJYFLZdRFTiVWqbRNmvadc6DTB3V7rbRbQmOg72E6Bi7DcbklAzWBLd6qL6gA)

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me mad as well, very nice solution !